# How to compare 2 ints in Jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

In my JPanel, I have a Jtextfield called for goals and in it i did
`int PGoals=10;`
`int PGoals=9;`
    `Goals.setText(Integer.toString(PGoals));`

In my other JTextField, I did

```
Goals2.setText(Integer.toString(PGoals2));
```

I want to do an if statement for

```
if(PGoals>Pgoals2){
```

`JTextfield.setText("Left Player has more goals");`
`}`

`else`
`{`
`JTextfield.setText("Right player has more goals");`

`}`

Comment: Use a JSpinner or JFormattedTextField instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(PGoals) > Integer.parseInt(Pgoals2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

if(Integer.parseInt(Goals.getText())>Integer.parseInt(Goals2.getText()))